# How to set maxAge dynamically in session in next-auth options in next.js 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

How to set checkbox value (stayLogin) from my client component directly to session options?
Now when I want set maxAge of the session in ...nextauth.ts, I can not pass/receive the stayLogin variable in nextauth.ts.
client component:

```
 onSubmit={async (values) => {
      const res = await signIn('login', {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        stayLogin: values.stayLogin,
        redirect: false,
      });
      if (res?.ok) {
        await router.push('/profile')
      } else {
        if (res?.error) {
          setLoginError(t(`Error.${res.error}`));
        }
      }
    }}
```

to my session options:

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: **//should be dynamical//**,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'login',
      name: 'login',
      type: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials: any) {
        if (!credentials) return null
        const variables = {
          "email": credentials?.email,
          "password": credentials?.password,
        }
        try {
          return await graphQLMutationClient(signIn, variables) as User;
        } catch (error: any) {
          throw new Error(error.response?.errors[0]?.message.replace(/\./g, ""));
        }
        return null
      }
    }),
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      if (user) return true;
      return false;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }: { session: any; user: any; token: any }) {
      console.log('tok', token)
      if (token.signin) {
        session.user.isLoggedIn = true;
        return session;
      } else if (token.signup) {
        session.user.isLoggedIn = true;
        return session;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const handler = NextAuth({
  ...authOptions
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I tried to use advanced options from next-auth, like get req.body , but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wow, I facing the same dilema right now .... I will keep track of this post, and if I find the solucion I'll come back here!